# System.Windows.Data is missing from my list of .NET libraries

Tags: .net

Hi I'd like to use System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter, but when I try to add a reference to System.Windows.Data in VS2010, I only see System.Windows.Forms and System.Windows.Presentation.  What am I missing?  I'm using .NET 3.5 (not the client version), and I think the library should exist for that version.  Switching my project to .NET 4.0 didn't help.  Googling didn't turn up any people experiencing this problem.  TIA.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Although [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) is in the `System.Windows.Data` *namespace*, it's in the `PresentationFramework` *assembly*. It's worth being aware of the difference between the two concepts. An assembly is the unit of deployment in .NET, but a single assembly can have types in multiple namespaces, and multiple assemblies can contribute types to the same namespace.

In practical terms, assemblies are what you add references to at the project level, and namespaces are what you have `using` directives for at the top of your source file :)

When you're not sure where a type is, in terms of either its namespace or its assembly, consult MSDN (such as the link above) which specifies both, like this:

> **Namespace:**  System.Windows.Data
>   **Assembly:**  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Comment: +1 as this was really helpful.  *However* I'm slightly confused - MSDN lists IValueConverter as being in System.Windows for Silverlight, but I actually needed to add a reference to PresentationFramework in order to get at it, as System.Windows wasn't in the list of available assemblies in my Silverlight project... weird!

Comment: Strange, PresentationFramework.dll is already added but still can't access System.Windows.Data

Comment: i had the same problem too. PresentationFramework.dll is present in all .NET packages installed yet unavailable to add as a reference in the list of available namespaces -  references.
Why should we reference some standard .dll by hand from location, why sometimes it unavailble?

Comment: @WebComer: You need to reference every DLL that isn't mscorlib - some project templates include common ones (and WPF templates would include PresentationFramework.dll for example). As for why it's not available for you - which version of .NET are you targeting? (It sounds like you should really be asking a new question, to be honest.)

Comment: I am targeting 4.5, the problem was solved by inclusion of PresentationFramework.dll by hand in the project. But i still guess, why other .dll 's are available, but this one. |The problem present in both Rider and VS. Probably poor template. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @WebComer: Well you haven't told us what kind of project you're using, for one thing - it's entirely reasonable for a console or WinForms app not to include it, for example.

Answer (score 4):

System.Windows.Data namespace comes from PresentationFramework.dll . Have you included it in your application (add new reference and so on)?

Comment: Yes, included i have included this dll.

Answer (score 3):

IValueConverter is now (Windows Phone 8.1, VS2013) available in Windows.UI.Xaml.Data

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a reference to Universal Api Contract and Windows Foundation Contract. These references allow you to use WPF libraries from console applications.