# Implement IValueConverter in class library project

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a solution with about 12 projects, one is set as the startup project and this contains the main window. At the moment all of my `IValueConverter`s are inside this project.

I now want to move them into a separate project that will hold only converters. This way I will be able to reuse them across all the projects, not just the main window.

- I have created a new project (class library)
- I have imported WindowsBase
- I have Included a reference to System.Windows.Data
- I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express with .NET 4

I get the error:

*"Error 3   The type or namespace name 'IValueConverter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
"

Comment: Have actually add a reference to you `IValueConverter` project in your other projects? You do not show it in your steps.

Comment: @rae1n: No, I haven't added the reference yet, I was just in the process of setting up the new project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add a reference to PresentationFramework.dll, that's where [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) is actually defined.

Looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) you can find that information at the top:

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Data
>   Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Comment: Sorry, was waiting for time limit and forgot.

Comment: Thank You for the hint! I needed it too. :)

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks. Described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538892/system-windows-data-is-missing-from-my-list-of-net-libraries
too.

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). I'm sure you're missing the library `PresentationFramework.dll` in your project.